# Как подвинуть стрелку в owl-carousel?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

Хочу выровнять стрелку навигации, но не получается к ней обратиться. Пишет, что в owl-next стрелка именуется элементом #text, но при обращении к этому элементу не происходит ничего. Как это исправить?

Весь код jsfiddle.net/94eqtuoy/
Сайт http://tempesv0.beget.tech/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По Вашему коду обратиться к ней можно только так (не знаю, уникальный ли у Вас `carousel-3d-container`, так что захватил уровень повыше):

```
#example .carousel-3d-controls .next span {
    color: #f00;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Не исключено, что этот класс будет перебит основными стилями, так что придётся прописывать `!important`.

Если вы используете пакет vue-owl-carousel, обратите внимание, что в компоненте [присутствуют слоты для элементов навигации](https://github.com/s950329/vue-owl-carousel/blob/master/src/Carousel.vue) (`prev` и `next`), там можно объявить свой код-обертку со стрелочкой и своим уникальным классом, а там уже и двигать элемент как угодно.

Comment: Vue carousel я использую в другой галерее,  а здесь чисто owl-carousel

Comment: @Sort Так а зачем чистый, если это по сути то же самое, только в виде обертки для Vue? В любом случае, класс выше должен работать на чистом.